# How to prove that a language is not recursively enumerable

Tags: computability, proof-techniques, semi-decidability

How does one prove that some arbitrary language $L$ is **not** recursively enumerable?

I know I can prove that the language $L$ is recursively enumerable by constructing a Turing machine $M$ that accepts all words in the language (and the language would be even recursive if $M$ halts on all inputs).

But it is not clear to me how to prove that language in not RE. I was thinking about showing the fact, that such TM could not be constructed for a given language, but proving non-existence is always difficult.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are two methods.

## Consider the complement

**Theorem.** If a language $L$ and its complement are both RE, they are both recursive.

*Proof.* Decide whether $w\in L$ by enumerating $L$ and its complement in parallel and accept/reject as soon as $w$ appears in one of the enumerations. $\Box$

So, if you can prove that $L$ is not recursive but its complement is RE, then $L$ is not RE.

## Halting problems

**Theorem.** Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the class of Turing machines equipped with an oracle for the ordinary Turing machine halting problem. The halting problem for $\mathcal{M}$ is not RE.

*Proof.* Essentially the same as the proof that the ordinary Turing machine halting problem is not recursive. $\Box$

So, if you can reduce the halting problem for $\mathcal{M}$ to your problem, your problem is not RE.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more thing: I thought that the language $\{(R(M),w) | M$ halts on input $w\}$ (the set representing the halting problem) is recursively enumerable. How can I use it to prove that a problem is NOT in RE?

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood, perhaps because of a typo I just fixed. Any kind of machine has its own halting problem: "Does a machine $M$ of that type halt when given input $w$?" The halting problem $H$ for Turing machines is RE; the halting problem for Turing machines that have an oracle for $H$ is not RE.

Comment: Ok, perhaps I do not fully understand the concept of the oracle based TM but thanks for the answer! I will take a look at it.

Comment: @Smajl Wikipedia has a decent page on [oracle machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine). If that helps, great! If it doesn't, ask another question, as long as you can formulate something reasonably specific.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Are you saying that the halting problem is not r.e.?

Comment: @A.Schulz I'm saying that the halting problem for a class of oracle machines is not RE. The halting problem for ordinary Turing machines is RE.

Answer (score 4):

Some common techniques include:

We start by picking any $L'$ which is known to be non RE, e.g. we let $L'$ to be the complement of the halting problem. Then we prove the m-reduction $L' \leq_m L$. If we can do that, we can conclude that $L$ is not RE, since otherwise $L'$ would be RE -- contradiction.

The [Rice-Shapiro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%E2%80%93Shapiro_theorem) is a very convenient and widely applicable method to establish "non-RE" properties. It is not a silver bullet which always applies, but many common languages are covered by it.

Comment: I just realized that this question is very old, and was only recently bumped to the front page by an edit. Oh well -- I'll leave this answer here anyway...

Comment: There's no problem at all with having good new answers to old questions. In particular, we might hope to turn this into a reference question that we can use when people want help with their computation theory exercises. And Stack Exchange as a whole is supposed to be helpful to people who find the site by Googling for help with their own problems, not just the person who asked the original question.